# SQL Server CE locale not found

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I have SQL Server CE privately deployed to a group of machines on my network. Every so often, I receive this error from application connecting to this local database.

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The specified locale is not installed on this machine. Make sure you install the appropriate language pack. [ LCID = 1033 ]

I do not understand why this is happening. I know that 1033 is EN-US, and all of these machines are EN-US machines. I'm missing something here, but I have no idea what it is. This error is not consistent, and I cannot replicate it. But I continually receive automated emails when this exception is thrown.

Some more details.  1) I can connect to the database.  2) When I check GetDatabaseInfo for the connection, I see that the lcid for the database is indeed 1033.  3)  I'm using CE 4.0.0.0.  4) My system lcid is 1033.  5) I can see the sqlceer40xx.dll -- where xx is EN.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try use method Reapir from SqlCeEngine

Comment: I've tried that, and these databases verify successfully -- the files do not change when repaired.

Comment: Check that really SQL collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: I've done a GetDatabaseInfo on the connection and I can see that Locale ID is 1033

Comment: Have you tried to connect with LCID parameter in connection string?

Comment: LCID in the connection string has no effect on CE databases after initial creation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63525/discussion-between-sentinel21-and-steryd).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477339/sql-compact-4-exception

Comment: Can you connect to the particular failing database usinng `SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source = YourDB.sdf");` ?

Comment: I would verify if the database file is damaged or not http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172420%28v=sql.110%29.aspx